# Error in .g.cs file involving error CS1001

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

So every time I debug, the error CS 1001 says identifier can't be found. This is because every time the .g.cs file regenerates it changes the assembly tagline and adds a dot in front of the Identifier.
Ex:
`[assembly: global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlResourceIdAttribute("Learn4.MainPage.xaml", "MainPage.xaml", typeof(global::.MainPage))]`

The dot in front of MainPage in `typeof(global::.MainPage))` doesn't belong so I delete it but it keeps on being regenerated every time I click debug. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Let's edit your question, make it clear.

Comment: I want to know what is your current project, WPF or UWP? It will help me to know your problem clear.